# Iterating parameters in the model to set their values

Tags: swift, model

Is it possible to iterate a parameter in a model in swift to set a value to it?
Something like creating a new instance based on data from an array.  I would like to create a CSVDecoder that will allow me to create models based on data from a csv file.

I was thinking about creating an additional protocol, like the Codable protocol, which would allow me to create a new instance of the model if it belongs to the protocol - CSVDecodable

But to be able to create this, I need to iterate through the parameters in the model to be able to assign them a value

```swift
enum CSVDecoderError: Error {
    case missingCSVFile
}

protocol CSVDecodable { }

final class CSVDecoder {
    func decode<T:CSVDecodable>(_ type: T.Type, from named: String) throws {
        guard let csvPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: named, ofType: ".txt") else {
            throw CSVDecoderError.missingCSVFile
        }
        
        let csvContent = try String(contentsOfFile: csvPath, encoding: .utf8)
        
        var rows = csvContent.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        rows.removeFirst()

        for row in rows {
         var cells = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
         cells.map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\"\r")) }
       
         // Iterate model parametr
    }
}
```

Comment: Check maybe how https://github.com/dehesa/CodableCSV does it? There is also a list of a few other libs at the end.